# Changing iteration order during nested iteration

Tags: python, arrays, vb.net, iteration

Given two associative arrays, one array contains pointers to 3d point coordinates, the other array contains a hash/dictionary of surfaces. For every point in the first array, there will be only one matching surface found in the second array (where the point lay on the surface.)

We need to iterate through the points to find the matching surface (to then get the unit vector [ijk points] normal to the surface at that point.)

Brute force could iterate through every item in each list, breaking the iteration once each surface data point is found. Though I’ve already found in writing earlier versions of this program, astronomically numerous calculations will be performed, and I need to be efficient.

There will always be more points than surfaces, and the surfaces will be adjacent, meaning as I iteration through the points in a certain order, it’s more likely than not that the next point will be on the same surface as the last.

I’m wondering if I can run a loop which, for example, 
`for point n:` 
  `for surface i:` 
`does the point lay on the surface? if so, break` 
…and if the last ‘i’ value was 5, begin the next iteration at i=5 (and if the point wasn’t on surface 5, continue iterating through each surface.) It would be better if I could have it iterate in a order like: not 5? try 6; not 6? try 4——
Expanding on that idea, imagine that ‘i’ were organized in an 2d array. I.e: 
[1,2,3] 
[4,5,6] 
[7,8,9] 
And for n points:
For i surfaces: (continuing where I left off,) not 4? try 2; not 2? try 8.

I’m wondering if a ‘for’ loop won’t give me the versatility I need. (By the way, the program will likely be written in either Python or .NET) I’m thinking that I can make a while loop and write some sort of logic that will iterate the way I want. Am I trying to reinvent the wheel? Am I on the right track?

Comment: I would order the points and surfaces, so you can exit the loop early. With binary search you can probably find the surface that contains the Point the fastest.

Comment: How do you know (programmatically) that the point belongs to the surface? I think that's the most important part of this question.

Comment: It’s a two step process to see if the point belongs to the surface— there’s a scripting command that will return UV surface parameters given a reference point. Secondly, there’s a command that will return a point given UV parameters. The two will only match if the point lay on the face.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer, because your question doesn't have a lot of specifics on what your actual code is.  But, that said, one thing to note is that the variable from a `for` loop retains its value even after the loop has ended.  So this will print 5:

```
for i in range(1000):
    if i == 5:
        break
print(i)
```

So you can easily check after the inner loop what value it ended on.  And then you can do whatever you want with that value.  For instance, you could look at it on the next run through the outer loop and fix things up so that the inner loop starts at some other place.

A `for` loop will almost surely give you the versatility you need, because you can use a for loop to iterate over many kinds of things, including some custom iterator that you create.  So for instance you could do something like this:

```
def best_order_to_loop(all_surfaces, previous_stopping_point):
    # some logic here
    yield next_value

previous_stopping_point = None
for point in points:
    surfaces_in_order = best_order_to_loop(all_surfaces, previous_stopping_point)
    for surface in surfaces_in_order:
        # do whatever
    previous_stopping_point = surface
```

Again, this is just a sketch and I'm not sure I'm 100% understanding your setup.  But it seems like you're saying "if the previous loop stopped at X, then based on that I want the next loop to loop in such-and-such order".  If that is the case you can write a function like `best_order_to_loop` that determines how the next inner loop will go, based on the previous stopping point.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Regarding Charles comment on binary search, I’m not sure I’ll be able to sort them in a way that would give a definitive beginning and end. For example, if you had a cad model of a candy cane, and you grabbed a collection of random points falling on the surface of the candy cane, then you need to find out if the points are located on a red surface or white surface, how would you use binary search if the array can be cyclical?

Comment: (Maybe the candy cane example isn’t great because there’s only two choices—it’s a multicolored candy cane I guess)

Comment: BrenBarn, I think I understand what you’re saying— I just have to make sure that the number of iterations running the extra best_order_to_loop function won’t end up exceeding the the number of iterations just running a linear search

Comment: FWIW since the question mentions .NET and includes the vb.net tag, the code in this answer appears that it would translate directly to VB.